# $\int x^k\ d\mu(x)\geq0$ for $k$ even?

Tags: measure-theory, convex-optimization, moment-problem

I am studying convex optimization, and the truncated moment problem is being discussed. I have no background in measure theory so I don't understand things taken for granted such as $$\int x^k\ d\mu(x)\geq0 \text{ for }k\text{ even}.$$
Could someone explain how this is true? I attempt to evaluate by doing:
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^k\ d\mu(x)&=
\int x^k\mu'(x)\ dx
\end{align}
$$
which seems like I could pick any $\mu'(x)$ and force the integral to be $<0$. Is there perhaps some restraint on $\mu$ that can be explained?

Comment: The integral of a non-negative function is non-negative, i.e $$f \geq 0 \implies \int f(x) \, d\mu(x) \geq 0.$$ Note that $f(x) := x^k$ is non-negative for even $k$.

Comment: @saz what if we let $\mu(x)=-x$? Because then $$\int f(x)\ d\mu(x) = \int -f(x)\ dx \leq 0$$

Comment: Well, I was indeed assuming that you are talking about **non-negative** measures

Comment: @saz I don't know anything about measure theory but I assume you are correct. Are there typical such restrictions on $\mu(x)$? For example, if we have $\mu(x)=x^{k}$, then $$\int x^k\ d\mu(x)=\int x^k k x^{k-1}\ dx\propto \int x^{2k-1}\ dx,$$ which is an integral of an odd function.

Comment: You will need to specify the domain of integration. The statement $d\mu(x) = k x^{k-1} \, dx$ is only true for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: The idea is, to find a non-negative $g$ with given moments $\int x^ng(x)dx$. It is possible that $g$ might have $\delta$-function spikes, so it turns out to be technically better to work with $\mu (x)$, a non-decreasing function which may have steps. Roughly speaking.